# Hibernate session and concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency, persistence

I am quite new with Hibernate and I have this newbie question in my head the clear answer to which I couldn't find anywhere online.

In my multithreaded application I want to use Hibernate for data persistence. The app by nature is event based, means that new event will spawn new thread to process incoming data. From one of online `Getting Started` tutorials I implemented Hibernate Session Factory which will create single session object and will return it upon `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`. From same tutorial I use this factory as follows:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

/*
    do smth here
*/

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

What I want to clarify is since there is only one session object shared across different threads will the concurrency work with this code?

For example I am not clear how it will handle situations when 1st thread started transaction, then 2nd thread started transaction, then 1st thread tries to commit transaction, which transaction will it commit? Since I am apllying HQL or Criteroins to Session object, would it know which transaction it should be applied to?

Comment: It's quite a time ago I read the hibernate manual. But at that point it wasn't thread safe. So this have to checked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry about a session being shared across multiple threads. By default the `SessionFactory` will bind a `Session` per thread in each of the 3 possible configurations. Here it is an extract from Hibernate 4 docs:

> However, as of version 3.1, the processing behind SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is now pluggable. To that end, a new extension interface, org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext, and a new configuration parameter, hibernate.current_session_context_class, have been added to allow pluggability of the scope and context of defining current sessions.
>
> ...
>
> Out-of-the-box, Hibernate comes with three implementations of this interface:
>
> org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext: current sessions are tracked and scoped by a JTA transaction. The processing here is exactly the same as in the older JTA-only approach. See the Javadocs for details.
>
> org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext:current sessions are tracked by thread of execution. See the Javadocs for details.
>
> org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext: current sessions are tracked by thread of execution. However, you are responsible to bind and unbind a Session instance with static methods on this class: it does not open, flush, or close a Session.

Comment: Please see my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989277/hibernate-session-and-concurrency/25991097#comment40700703_25990200 can you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Not quite. There is one session per thread. `getCurrentSession()` returns the same session object for the same request thread. In different request threads it creates (once) and returns different session objects.

Comment: So as long as within one thread I don't do two overlapping transactions I should be safe? Is it worth creating new session if I need to do two overlapping transactions within one thread?

Comment: Yes, you are safe. You shouldn't mix transactions on the same database, why would you need such a thing? If there are 2 different databases use 2 SessionFactory(s).

Comment: About overlapping transactions - this is just a theoretical question to help me understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SessionFactory** - It shared single object to whole application.It is threadsafe.

**Session** - It will be created for every application request. It does share with any other object and It is not threadsafe.

Comment: So for every time I call `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession` it actually creates new object with same parameters? Then as long as I use one session for each event (as in code above), then I am good-to-go ready for fully concurrent application and no further setup or changes are required. Do I understand it correctly?